# iphone html5 video touch events

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, video

**iphone only** question

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TLAkf/9/) (try to touch video)

```
<div class="video">
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <video id="player1" width="540" height="303" preload="none">
    <source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>

.video {
  position : relative;
  width    : 540px;
  height   : 303px;
}
.video .empty {
  position : absolute;
  z-index  : 1;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
}

$("*").add(document).add(window)
.bind(
  "touchstart touchend touchcancel touchleave touchmove",
  function() { alert(1); }
);
```

html5 video controls cant be turned off, but video controls dont propagate any events (particularly touch events).

Is there any workaround?